# Wifi RSSI signal to distance calculation method with javascript

Tags: javascript, rss, wifi, distance, rssi

Is there a method  to convert a RSSI signal to an exact distance? We tryed several formulas but all with a different result.

The formula where i'm talking about:

`public double calculateDistance(double signalLevelInDb, double freqInMHz) {
    double exp = (27.55 - (20 * Math.log10(freqInMHz)) + Math.abs(signalLevelInDb)) / 20.0;
    return Math.pow(10.0, exp);
}`

Comment: What formulas have you tried? Also, how different were the results? The results are typically going to be different through no fault of the formulas, but rather the inaccuracy inherent in this kind of calculation. [This link](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/83354/calculate-distance-from-rssi) might be helpful, in case you haven't seen it already.

Comment: I edited my poste with the formula where I'm talking about. 
It's difficult to verify if the results are correct since (as we know) the RSSI signales aren't accurate with all the noise made by other devices and objects in the room. @0101001101000010

Answer (score 2):

RSSI and dBm measure strength, which is dependent on many factors, one of which is of course distance from the source.  RSSI is relative to the chipset of the device (see http://www.metageek.com/training/resources/understanding-rssi.html).  Unless you javascript can know the chipset of the device, I don't beleive there is a way that you can do what you want.

If you have the signal strength in dBm, you could attempt to classify an "effective" distance, which would approximate the distance based on the signal strength, but even that is mitigated by other factors such as the medium through which the signal travels, the frequency band used by the signal (2.4 penetrates better than 5Ghz e.g.)

It sounds like you really need geolocation services so you can identify the actual distance between the device and the access point.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but we found a possible formula (which makes use of the frequency :) ), but we aren't sure if the results are correct. It's difficult to verify if the results are correct since (as we know) the RSSI signales aren't accurate with all the noise made by other devices and objects in the room.

The formula where i'm talking about:

 `public double calculateDistance(double signalLevelInDb, double freqInMHz) {
   double exp = (27.55 - (20 * Math.log10(freqInMHz)) +  Math.abs(signalLevelInDb)) / 20.0;
   return Math.pow(10.0, exp);
 }`

@jk72

Comment: @A.vk  This link explains pretty well the process and the problems inherent in what you are doing: http://electronicdesign.com/communications/understanding-wireless-range-calculations